# Native script Listview not showing properly

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have a page where at the top I am showing an ActionBar, and below that I saw a SegmentedBar. For first tab of the SegmentedBar I show a list. The list is rendering, but not taking remaining space. Here is my code -

```
<ActionBar title="NS Learning" android:position="right">
    <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" horizontalAlignment="stretch">
       <Label text="Jahid Shohel" horizontalAlignment="center"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</ActionBar>
<GridLayout rows="auto, *" columns="*">
    <SegmentedBar row="0" #tabs [items]="items" [(ngModel)]="selectedIndex" selectedBackgroundColor="#fac950"></SegmentedBar>

    <StackLayout row="1" *ngIf="selectedIndex === 0" height="stretch">
        <tab1></tab1>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout row="1" *ngIf="selectedIndex === 1" width="100%">
        <tab2></tab2>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout row="1" *ngIf="selectedIndex === 2" width="100%">
        <tab3></tab3>
    </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

And my `<tab1></tab1>` code is -

```
<DockLayout>
    <ListView [items]="items" dock="top">
        <template let-item="item">
            <GridLayout columns="auto, *, auto" rows="auto,auto">
                <Image row="0" rowSpan="2" col="0" src="res://user" class="post-image"></Image>
                <Label row="0" col="1" colSpan="2" text="Good morning! Have a nice day"></Label>
                <Image row="1" col="1" src="res://facebook_thumb" class="social-icon"></Image>
                <Label row="1" col="2" text="15 August 2016 11:17:26"></Label>
            </GridLayout>
        </template>
    </ListView>
</DockLayout>
```

And the rendered list is like this -

[image]

Any idea how can I fix that?

Comment: You could try to use GridLayout instead of DockLayout for a container for your ListView.

Comment: @NikolayTsonev: It worked, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Apply height attribute on ListView with value "100%"

```
<ListView [items]="items" dock="top" height="100%">
```